# Opencpu App-Development process and deployment

Tags: r, apache2, opencpu

I found an R package `opencpu-demo` which gets installed as an App on the server. However it isn't clear which files the user needs to explicitly create in the `/install` directory and how to tie it with R functions. Does it require JavaScript embedded with R or vice-versa. Any help or pointer to a tutorial will be greatly appreciated.